# displaying an array of high scores

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am still pretty new to objective-c and I am doing a finale project for my class. What i want to do is read from NSUserDefaults the array of 3 high scores and display them on the first screen.

Here is my code

```
 self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *highscores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults arrayForKey:@"highscores"]];

    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    myLabel.text = @"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",highscores(0),highscores(1),highscores(2); //error on this line
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:myLabel];
```

when i try to pass the highscores i get a error that NSArrays are not functions or function points

Comment: Try `myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",highscores[0],highscores[1],highscores[2]];`

Comment: thanks that did it but should i use %@ instead of %f

Comment: myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",[highscores[0] floatValue],[highscores[0] floatValue],[highscores[0] floatValue]];

Answer (score 1):

Edit the line of error with this line,

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",
[[highscores objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],
[[highscores objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],
[[highscores objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

replace line

```
myLabel.text = @"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",highscores(0),highscores(1),highscores(2);
```

with

```
myLabel.text = @"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",[highscores objectAtIndex:0],[highscores objectAtIndex:1],[highscores objectAtIndex:2];
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try bellow code .......
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *highscores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults arrayForKey:@"highscores"]];

highscores = [highscores sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                            ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) {
                                    return NSOrderedAscending;
                                } else if ([obj1 intValue] > [obj2 intValue]) {
                                    return NSOrderedDescending;
                                } else {
                                    return NSOrderedSame;
                                }
                            }];
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    myLabel.text = @"High Scores \n 1)%f \n 2)%f \n 3) %f",highscores(0),highscores(1),highscores(2); //error on this line
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:myLabel];
```